# Messed up "/etc/bash.bashrc" cannot edit it again

Tags: bash, debian

I tried to export a PATH to /etc/bash.bashrc file, but I added some invalid identifiers. Now I am not able to access program such as ls, nano, vi, gedit from the terminal, and that's why couldn't correct the /etc/bash.bashrc file. How can I edit it in this situation? Thank you!

Comment: Question probably belongs on http://superuser.com/

Comment: I wasn't aware. Thanks! Will take care from the next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On my Ubuntu the *nano* and *vi* programs live in */usr/bin*.  So you might try

```
$ sudo /usr/bin/nano /etc/bash.bashrc
$ sudo /usr/bin/vi /etc/bash.bashrc
```

Comment: Thanks everyone! This method worked but I have a different issue now. Now even after removing all the lines I included that messed up the file, the commands are still not working (without the complete path). I should have taken a back-up of the original file, but I didn't. Do you think I can get a copy of that file? or any other way to fix this new issue? Thanks again!

Comment: Copy of your bashrc? Just move your current one elsewhere to back it up and do `mv /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc`

Comment: I appreciate everyone here for their help. The commands started working (without giving complete path) when I corrected back the /etc/bash.bashrc file and made a reboot.

Comment: @BroSlow `mv` not, but `cp`

Comment: @Braiam Woops, thanks for the correction. Meant move current one away and copy skel, wrote it backwards.

Answer (score 1):

You can do one of two things:

1) Use full path of vi to edit /etc/bash.bashrc file:

```
/usr/bin/vi /etc/bash.bashrc
```

2) Correct the path on the command line then fix:

```
export PATH=...
vi /etc/bash.bashrc
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat /etc/bash.bashrc 
# System-wide .bashrc file for interactive bash(1) shells.

# To enable the settings / commands in this file for login shells as well,
# this file has to be sourced in /etc/profile.

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, overwrite the one in /etc/profile)
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '

# Commented out, don't overwrite xterm -T "title" -n "icontitle" by default.
# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
#case "$TERM" in
#xterm*|rxvt*)
#    PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;${USER}@${HOSTNAME}: ${PWD}\007"'
#    ;;
#*)
#    ;;
#esac

# enable bash completion in interactive shells
#if ! shopt -oq posix; then
#  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
#    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
#  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
#    . /etc/bash_completion
#  fi
#fi

# sudo hint
if [ ! -e "$HOME/.sudo_as_admin_successful" ] && [ ! -e "$HOME/.hushlogin" ] ; then
    case " $(groups) " in *\ admin\ *)
    if [ -x /usr/bin/sudo ]; then
    cat <<-EOF
    To run a command as administrator (user "root"), use "sudo <command>".
    See "man sudo_root" for details.

    EOF
    fi
    esac
fi

# if the command-not-found package is installed, use it
if [ -x /usr/lib/command-not-found -o -x /usr/share/command-not-found/command-not-found ]; then
    function command_not_found_handle {
            # check because c-n-f could've been removed in the meantime
                if [ -x /usr/lib/command-not-found ]; then
           /usr/lib/command-not-found -- "$1"
                   return $?
                elif [ -x /usr/share/command-not-found/command-not-found ]; then
           /usr/share/command-not-found/command-not-found -- "$1"
                   return $?
        else
           printf "%s: command not found\n" "$1" >&2
           return 127
        fi
    }
fi
```

Comment: Thanks! Though I couldn't try it, as my problem got solved by rebooting the machine.

Comment: its nice to have this here, i've used this several times to replace "missing" ones on my old servers, what build does this come from (ie, the output from 'uname -a + bash --version') always would help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a full path on the command line like

```
$ /usr/bin/nano /etc/bash.bashrc
```

That way you can pull up nano and edit it.

Answer (score 0):

You could also attempt to run `/bin/sh` to get a "standard" shell.